# Top positioned Xamarin forms listview with a header - problem: top position varies on some iPhone models

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to set the height of the list view so that the bottom view cell is not cut off whenever adding or removing a view item.  I can achieve it for some iPhone models, but not the others. It seems it’s not a right way to achieve it by iPhone model. My questions are:
1.  On some iPhone models, why the top position shifts down by about 25 pixels after adding a view item?
2.  How to find the absolute top position Y coordinate of the list view?

It seems AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" doesn’t help. VerticalOptions="Start" doesn’t help either.

Note: 
1. no such an issue on Android phones. 
2. Observation only: It seems that changing the margin of the listview header brandStack has no effect on the layout, eg. cannot see increased margins.
3. The following two screenshots show that the top position of the listview header has moved down a bit after an item is added to the listview.

[image: initial layout on some iPhones]

[image: layout after adding an item to the listview]

[image: use iOS SafeArea]

[image: set BackgroundColor to gradient color start]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="tecommobile.Views.PanelsHomePage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:effects="clr-namespace:tecommobile.Effects;assembly=tecommobile"
             xmlns:tecommobile="clr-namespace:tecommobile;assembly=tecommobile"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:tecommobile.Views;assembly=tecommobile"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Flex.Controls;assembly=Flex"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=netstandard"
             x:Name="PanelHomePage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             BackgroundColor="Bisque"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="addPanelStyle" TargetType="views:CustomImageButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource customImageButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="panel_add.png" />
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="70" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <RelativeLayout>
            <tecommobile:GradientColorStack RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                                                   Property=Height,
                                                                                                   Factor=1}"
                                            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                                                  Factor=1}"
                                            Style="{StaticResource gradientColorStack}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="panelListViewStack" BackgroundColor="Red"
                                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" BackgroundColor="Orange"
                              Margin="15"
                              CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="false"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                              RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                              SelectionMode="None"
                              Style="{StaticResource listViewNoSeparatorStyle}"
                              Scrolled="ItemsListView_OnScrolled">
                            <ListView.Header>
                                <StackLayout x:Name="brandStack" Margin="15, 0, 15, 0" HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                                    <Image HeightRequest="48"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Source="Icon_ILXLinks.png"
                                           WidthRequest="48"
                                           Margin="0,30,0,0" />
                                    <Label FontSize="20"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="TecomPlus"
                                           TextColor="White"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Label FontSize="14"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="Your smart security manager"
                                           TextColor="White"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,20" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ListView.Header>
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <Grid effects:RoundCornersEffect.CornerRadius="8" HeightRequest="75" Margin="2" BackgroundColor="{Binding PanelColour}">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding BindingContext.EditToggleIcon, Source={x:Reference PanelHomePage}}"
                                                       BackgroundColor="Transparent" WidthRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.HomePageEditPanelCommand, Source={x:Reference PanelHomePage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                                          NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                       LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontSize="14" TextColor="{Binding PanelTextColour}">
                                            </Label>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="forward.png" Style="{StaticResource rightImageStyle}">
                                            </Image>
                                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.RunPanelCommand, Source={x:Reference PanelHomePage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                                  NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout HeightRequest="70"></StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BackToEditCommand}"/>
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                </StackLayout>
                <tecommobile:GradientColorStack.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BackToEditCommand}"/>
                </tecommobile:GradientColorStack.GestureRecognizers>
            </tecommobile:GradientColorStack>
            <views:CustomImageButton Command="{Binding InfoCommand}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                   HeightRequest="30"
                   WidthRequest="30"
                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                     Property=Width,
                                                                     Factor=1,
                                                                     Constant=-45}"
                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                     Property=Height,
                                                                     Factor=0,
                                                                     Constant=35}"
                   Source="info.png">
            </views:CustomImageButton>

            <Grid x:Name="bottomGrid" BackgroundColor="#216593" effects:RoundCornersEffect.CornerRadius="8"
                  RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-140}"
                  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-70}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.0*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1.0*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="AddButton" Source="panel_add.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Style="{StaticResource buttonImageStyle}">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Image x:Name="DeleteButton" Source="{Binding BindingContext.DeleteToggleIcon, Source={x:Reference PanelHomePage}}" 
                                         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource buttonImageStyle}">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ToggleDeleteIconCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference DeleteButton}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you please share us some code about the issues? We can't debug without any code. You can add bottom view to the footer of listView then it will be fixed at the bottom of listView.

Comment: UI Images and code will help answering your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top position shifts down because the margin you set in the listView:

```
 <ListView BackgroundColor="Orange" Margin="15">
```

Remove the  `Margin="15"` and the space will disappear.

BTW, you can add [page-safe-area-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) to make it looks better:

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             Title="Safe Area"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <StackLayout>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Hi Jack Hua, Thanks. So I can change the Margin to "15,0,15,0". Can you explain why the space is always present on every Android phone but only on some later iPhones (also only appears after adding an item to list view)? The initial loading has no such a space / margin rendered. Good to know page-safe-area-layout. I like it. I will use it.

Comment: Thanks to David Ortinau (Principal Program Manager, Mobile Developer Tools, Xamarin SDKs) and Jack Hua. Yes, iOS SafeArea makes the problem go away. Now the remaining issue is that the top bar on any iPhone is highlighted with unwanted color. See the attached screenshot 3.

Comment: The color is the backgroundcolor of your contentPage, you set `BackgroundColor="Bisque"` in your code. Set whatever color you want to achieve your requirement. Don't forget to mark this answer if it solves your problem so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: I set BackgroundColor="Bisque" for test. If I don't set it, the color is white. I want GradientColor from top to bottom. See GradientColorStack in my code.

Comment: @HongWang You can set the backgroundcolor of contentPage a  GradientColor.

Comment: I have set the background color to the gradient start color. See screenshot 4.It's better. The top inset is good. But the bottom inset is slightly different. But it seems impossible to show the gradient end color at the home indicator in addition to the gradient start color at the top. It seems that setting the GradientColorStack in the content page doesn't help.

Comment: I don't know how do you set the GradientColorStack, what I'm sure is that the color you need to set is the backgroundColor of contentPage. Maybe you can open a new thread and add your color code there because it looks like a new problem.

Comment: Hi Jack Hua, that's OK. Thanks for your support.